# Why can't I reinstall Module Magento?

Tags: magento2, database, magento-1, script, setup

I have a module in magento, and the script setup module. Now I want to re-run this script and this module.
I deleted the setup of this module in core_resource, and access magento. But the module is not reinstalled. The database of this module isn't deleted, although I have DROP TABLE IF EXIST in scripts. And in the core_resource, the setup of this module not exists, it is really deleted. So I think the setup not run. But this module still work normally with old sql and no setup field in core_resource.

Comment: Did you delete cache?

Answer (score 2):

This possibly is a cache or compilation issue. The module may still be working in the frontend, but in fact be disabled. So check the status of the module in `System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced` and also in `app/etc/modules/yourmodule.xml`. In this file you should see `<active>true</active>`.

If the module is properly enabled and flushing all cache did not help then this is what I would do in this situation (it's quite a lot of work):

1. First, make sure you have a complete backup (file system and database)
2. Then make sure compilation is disabled in `System > Tools > Compilation`
3. Disable all cache in `System > Cache Management`
4. Disable the troubling module in `System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced`
5. Logout of the admin panel
6. Use FTP or SSH to remove all of the modules directories and files from the file system
7. Use FTP or SSH to delete the following directories (if present)

   ```
   [your Magento install dir]/includes/src/
   [your Magento install dir]/media/css/
   [your Magento install dir]/media/css_secure/
   [your Magento install dir]/media/js/
   [your Magento install dir]/var/cache/
   ```

> **IMPORTANT:** Don't delete the entire `includes/` `media/` and `var/` directories, only
>   the subdirectories I mentioned above!

8. Reinstall the module by uploading all files
9. Login to the admin panel
10. Enable the troubling module in `System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced`
11. Clear all cache again in `System > Cache Management`
12. Reindex in `System > Index Management`
13. Logout of the admin panel and back in

If this doesn't help then repeat all steps above and between steps 6 and 7 do the following:

6,5. Remove all tables and entries of the module from the database. After `core_resource` don't forget to also check the `core_config_data` table for entries of the troubling module

> **NOTE:** You will lose al your modules settings when performing this final step

Hope this is helpful!